# Spring Integration Boundary Logging

Tags: java, oracle, spring-integration, ibm-mq, jetty-9

I have a Spring Integration application deployed on Jetty which picks messages (both XML and JSON) from IBM MQ, does some transformations and persists the transformed messages to Oracle.

We are doing load testing at the moment, and the performance is quite poor, ~ approximately **15 messages per second** being drained from the queue in our NFT environment. Even though our Monitoring tool; AppD is showing us it takes only ~20ms to persist to Oracle and almost nothing on the other steps.

When building on our local machines we can see a significantly higher throughput (~100 messges per second) and I want to validate this with some boundary logging; i.e for the speed of pulling messages off and speed of persisting messages to the DB. It might help identify bottlenecks or even network issues.

I am using a message-driven-channel-adapter

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
        channel="routingChannel"
        container="DefaultJmsListenerContainer" />
```

and the MQ connections; with 5-10 for concurrency

```
    public MQQueue createRequestQueue() throws IllegalStateException, JMSException {
    return new MQQueue(env.getRequiredProperty(QUEUE_MANAGER), incomingQueue);
}

    @Bean(name="DefaultJmsListenerContainer")
 public DefaultMessageListenerContainer provideJmsListenerContainer() throws IllegalStateException, JMSException {
     DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
     container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());     
     container.setTransactionManager(provideTransactionManager());
     container.setConcurrency(jmsConcurrency);
     container.setCacheLevel(jmsCacheLevel);
     container.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
     container.setSessionTransacted(true);
     container.setDestination(createRequestQueue());

     return container;
 }

    @Bean(name="MQConnectionFactory")
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

    if (factory == null) {
        factory = new MQConnectionFactory();
        try {
            factory.setConnectionNameList(env.getRequiredProperty(HOST));
            factory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getRequiredProperty(PORT)));            
            factory.setQueueManager(env.getRequiredProperty(QUEUE_MANAGER));
            factory.setChannel(env.getRequiredProperty(CHANNEL));
            factory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            factory.setSSLCipherSuite(env.getRequiredProperty(SSL_CIPHER_SUITE));
            factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, env.getRequiredProperty(QUEUE_USERID));
            factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, env.getRequiredProperty(QUEUE_PASSWORD));

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return factory;
}


     @Bean(name = "jmsTransactionManager")
 public JmsTransactionManager provideTransactionManager() {      
     return new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory());
 }

    @Bean(name="jdbcTransactionManager")
public DataSourceTransactionManager jdbcTransactionManager() {
    DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return dataSourceTransactionManager;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);        
    DataSource  dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/pxxds");        
    return dataSource;
}
```

For the Oracle persistence part, I am using a ServiceActivator to call a JDBCTemplace for the payload (write model) persistence and queueing the messages in a QueueChannel and using an aggregator for Batch Hibernate Persistence (read model)

When I see blogs like the one below, processing a million transactions per second, it is quite facinating and I want to find the root cause

> https://fr.slideshare.net/joshlong/dynamic-routing-at-1-million-messages-per-second-with-spring-integration

I am also unsure how to proceed if I were to read 10 messages from the queue and then persist in batch, how should the message-driven-channel-adapter be configured and still ensure that the JMS Transaction Management is working along with the JDBC Transaction Management.

I could not find a well explained article on Spring Integration's transaction management when using 2 transaction managers as it is in my case. And the requirement on our side is to achieve **zero data loss**, so its important for me to understand.

So 2 questions:

1. how to configure boundary logging for the current scenario
2. is there any discrepancies that are apparent from the configuration above

Cheers
Kris

Comment: Too much questions in one SO thread. That’s not how things work here

Comment: Hi Artem...agreed...but, I feel they are all related to the current performance issues through.

Comment: Maybe you really can show your whole integration flow?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are mentioning a `QueueChannel`. This one is really based on some poller and if it is configured for something like `fixedDelay = 1000`, so that is going to be some bottleneck. Another option to consider for this poller is a `maxMessagesPerPoll = -1`.

I'm not sure what is your `boundary logging`. Never heard such a term, but you really can turn on DEBUG logging level for the `org.springframework.integration` and you'll see in logs how messages are traveling through the Spring Integration components.

For the `DataSourceTransactionManager` and `JmsTransactionManager` combination we always recommend to read Dave Syer's article about 1PC Distributed Transactions article: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html. Also there is already a `ChainedTransactionManager` in the Spring Data on the matter.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I am reading the article. But regarding the CachingConnectionFactory, we were using it and I removed it because I read the API documentation below, which mentions not to use the latter when using concurrent users. [link] https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html. I also updated the description with the IBM Queue that we create to connect to the queue.